# In Netbeans how do you set the equivalent of Eclipse's run/debug configuration arguments?

Tags: java, netbeans

I've inherited a java app that uses a XML as input. From the command line it runs like this:

java -jar myJar.jar -f /path/to/my/xmlfile.xml

In eclipse you can set run/debug config args from the Run->Debug Configurations... (arguments tab). How do you set the equivalent in Netbeans?

Don't know if it makes a difference but it's a Netbeans maven project.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have NetBeans right now, so you might adapt this, but you can just right click on the project, and in the "Set configuration" submenu, you just choose "Manage configurations", which will lead you to the right dialog.
Then you'll be able to choose the main class and arguments.

Comment: Sent me in the right direction, the complete sequence is right-click on the project folder and select properties, then click on Configurations and add one, then click on Run select your configuration from the drop-down and add arguments in appropriate field.

Comment: @kreek - I'm trying to do the same thing but I'm not sure what to enter for Execute Goals.  I mean, is there an option for debugging?