# is there a way or a general guideline as to how to perform the function of command line in IDE?

Tags: java, command-line

The Java tutorials on Oracle uses command line to execute the program as well as instruct it to perform certain actions. I was just wondering if it is possible to perform those using an IDE instead of command line?

Comment: Of course it is possible.

Comment: is there a guideline as to how it could be done? The java tutorial oracle i'm currently reading uses command line, but I uses netbeans instead. And I have no idea how to perform some of the command line instructions using netbeans.

Comment: command line is often called "console" in an IDE.

Comment: Every IDE also has a help page, so read it.

Comment: for example, how do I execute " java -Djava.security.manager GetProps " in netbeans? I have provided the link to the tutoiral containing this code. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour2/step2.html

Comment: @Meier thank you very much for the suggestion. I have tried to create an console in my code, but the IDE returned a null. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tom if it is not too much trouble, could you please point to me the right help page?

Comment: [In Netbeans how do you set the equivalent of Eclipse's run/debug configuration arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6947626)